# An element node 'soap:Envelope' of the type Element was expected, but node 's:envelope' of type Element was found

Tags: python, outlook, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, exchangelib

I get this with EWS when I try to get emails from my adresse.

This my code and it was working fine

```
from exchangelib import Account, Credentials, Configuration, Message, DELEGATE, Mailbox, FileAttachment, HTMLBody, FolderCollection
from exchangelib.protocol import BaseProtocol, NoVerifyHTTPAdapter
from exchangelib.folders import Folder
import warnings



warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
BaseProtocol.HTTP_ADAPTER_CLS = NoVerifyHTTPAdapter

credentials = Credentials(username='**domain\\XXXXXXXXXX**', password='**XXXXXXXXXXX**')

config = Configuration(server='**XXXXXXXXXXX**', credentials=credentials)
account = Account(primary_smtp_address='**XXXXXXXXXXX@COMPANY.COM**', config=config, autodiscover=False, access_type=DELEGATE)

for email in account.inbox.all().order_by('-datetime_received')[:8]:
    print(str(email.subject))
```

Comment: Please post the full stack trace here. Also, did you change anything since it was working fine?

Comment: The wording hints at invalid XML sent by the server. You can see the exact XML if you enable debug logging. See https://ecederstrand.github.io/exchangelib/#troubleshooting